# SQL Substring - Remove Last Character(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, text, sql-update, substr

I have a SQL query that brings back 2 columns of data both of TYPE TEXT.

What i am trying to do is:

```
UPDATE [DBNAME}
SET [3 15] = SUBSTR([3 15], -1))
where [3 15] LIKE  '%;'
```

Where [3 15] is the column name, i would like to pull the data from that column which has ends in a ';' and then remove the trailing ';'

This would be easy if the column type was string but its not.

Running on a: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - Developer Edition

Comment: It is of type text the column.

Comment: which database and version is this ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - Developer Edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change that text field to varchar(max) as soon as possible. However here is a solution that should work:

```
declare @a table([3 15] text)
insert @a values('aba;;;')
insert @a values('123abc;;')
insert @a values('abdc;')
insert @a values('abkjfshc')
insert @a values(';;;;')

;with a as
(
SELECT [3 15], cast([3 15] as varchar(max)) v 
-- replace @a with your actual tablename
FROM @a
)
UPDATE a
SET [3 15] = left(v, len(v)-patindex('%;[^;]%', reverse(v) + '+') + 1)
WHERE [3 15] LIKE  '%;;' -- notice the change

select * from @a
```

Result:

```
3 15
aba;
123abc;
abdc;
abkjfshc
;
```

EDIT:

To replace all combinations of '%;;%' within the text:

```
declare @a table([3 15] text)
insert @a values('aba;;;')
insert @a values('123abc;;')
insert @a values('abdc;')
insert @a values('ab;;kjf;;;;;shc')
insert @a values(';;;;')

-- if any combinations of ';;' still exists repeat until they are gone
while exists (select 1 from @a where [3 15] like '%;;%')
with a as
(
SELECT [3 15], cast([3 15] as varchar(max)) v 
-- replace @a with your actual tablename
FROM @a
WHERE [3 15] LIKE  '%;;%' -- notice the change
)
UPDATE a
-- to speed things up i used several replace
SET [3 15] = replace(replace(replace(replace(v, ';;;;', ';'), ';;;', ';'), ';;;', ';'), ';;', ';')
```

Comment: Great answer one quick quesiton

How would id o something simple like there may be ;; within the string how do i remove it and replace it with just one ;

Comment: Great thanks, i thoughti edited the question to reflect this but the edit didnt go through

Comment: Hi great answer but once i again my falut by ;; i ment e.g liam;;david

so i would want to do a replace to look like liam;david

Comment: I.e something like this:  REPLACE((cast [3 15] as VARCHAR(MAX)),';;',';')

but i cant get that working

Comment: @LmC that is far from the description in your question and even the where clause you wrote. I made an edit to handle it

Answer (score 4):

Hope this sql will help you

```
SELECT LEFT('CHAMLY', LENGTH('CHAMLY') -1);
```

for further reading
use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: "CHAMLY" what is that ment to represent?

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'LENGTH' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: you have to replace colomn name for 'CHAMLY'. I use this sql to show how it working in mysql. you have to modify according to your requirement. i tried to explain how can over come from problem rather than correct sql. Use LEN for length. use this
UPDATE [DBNAME}
SET [3 15] = LEFT([3,15], LEN([3 15]) -1);
where [3 15] LIKE  '%;'

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table
SET someColumn = SUBSTRING(someColumn, 1, DATALENGTH(someColumn) - 1)
WHERE someColumn like '%;'
```

In your example, you say `UPDATE dbname` - I assume that is the name of a table, for some reason, because if that is the name of the database, then that isn't correct.

Comment: How would i do a replace? like this:  REPLACE((cast [3 15] as VARCHAR(MAX)),';;',';') 

that doesnt seem to work for me :(

Comment: Your syntax was a little off, use this: REPLACE(CAST([3 15] as VARCHAR(MAX)), ';;', ';')

Answer (score 0):

a simple one

```
UPDATE Table SET column = LEFT(column,-1)
```